# Laravel Authorization para multi Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-auth, authorization, acl

Tenho uma aplicação ACL para Laravel onde possuo duas sessões(***guards***), uma para ***users*** e outra para ***admins***.

A configuração do ***guards*** no arquivo auth.php ficou assim:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Crebs86\TrustMultiAuth\Model\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Crebs86\TrustMultiAuth\Model\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
```

A função `boot()` do `AuthServiceProvider` fica dessa forma:

```
    public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    $permissions = Permission::with('roles')->get();
    foreach ($permissions as $permission):
        Gate::define($permission->name, function (User $user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    endforeach;
    Gate::before(function(User $user, $ability){
        if($user->hasAnyRoles('super-admin'))
            return true;
    });
}
```

Como se pode observar só consigo injetar um ***guard***, no caso o ***web*** `Gate::define($permission->name, function (User $user)...`, e toda a lógica baseada no controle de acesso funciona para o login feito no *model* ***User***,.

Porém não consigo captar o ***guard*** de origem da requisição e fazer a requisição para o *model* ***Admin*** quando este for o caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma solução durante o debug, editando o AuthServiceProvider assim:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        $permissions = Permission::with('roles')->select('id', 'name')->get()->toArray();
        foreach ($permissions as $permission):
            Gate::define($permission['name'], function ($user = null, $guard) use ($permission) {
                return $guard->hasPermission($permission['name']);
            });
        endforeach;
    }
```

Onde ... **$user=null** é o guard padrão esperado e **$guard** é o *Model* que você setou ao fazer a verificação.

Answer (score 0):

Cara to precisando fazer a mesma coisa, por favor se descobrir me avisa.

Tenho meu segundo Guard e também preciso acessar o Gate para outro Model

Comment: Olá. tente o que disse acima! Qualquer coisa pergunte aqui!

Comment: Cleber, show caraa!! funcionou mas somente com a opção $user = null.

Ai para eu pegar a permissão de qual usuário estava logando eu fiz no Model do Usuário
protected $guard = 'user';
e fiz a função
public function pegarGuard(){
        return $this->guard;
    }